# How to indent particular row in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and and I am creating it dynamically, I get parent and child tables records and binding the data to a single data grid view. I need to indent the row which is from child table a bit to the right so that i can differentiate the record from parent record.

```
private void CreateDynamicGridView(DataTable tables, GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable _dtSearchList = tables;
            strColumnCount = _dtSearchList.Columns.Count.ToString();                
                foreach (DataColumn col in _dtSearchList.Columns)
                {
                    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
                    bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName;
                    bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                    gv.Columns.Add(bfield);
                }
                gv.DataSource = _dtSearchList;
                gv.DataBind();                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did as follows,

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
     if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.IndexOf('Child') > 0){
           e.Row.Cells[0].Style.Add("padding-left", "16px");
     }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you insert it in the next column?

```
gv.Colums.Insert(2, col.ColumnName);
```

Comment: Both the tables are having same columns, so it has to be added to the same columns . just need to intent it a bit